# How to get drawing price on trading view chart in angular

Tags: tradingview-api

Trading view chart
Draw a drawing on Trading view chart, I need the Price range which is highlighted in Drawing area.
I'm searching for a method which return the price of a Drawing?
How to console Drawing Price in angular. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SGgk.png)